# How to get 1-100, 110-130 between numbers in python

Tags: python

How to get 1-100 between numbers in python, The scenario is user will enter in a char field like`1-100`, `110-120`, means I want to this format `[1,2,3,4,5...100]` and `[110,111,112,113...120]`, How to do this in python.

Comment: Split to begin with, generating a range shouldn't be too tough either.

Comment: Oh, the number of upvotes suggest what a quality question on StackOverflow should be like.  Good.

Comment: Which specific part of this challenge are you having trouble with? Parsing the input values, or generating the ranges? Or do you simply want others to write the code for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to pass a string like `1-100,110-120,140-15` or a string like `1-100` use,

```
def separator(string):
    if ',' in string:
        sep_strings = string.split(',')
        limits = [i.split('-') for i in sep_strings]
    else:
        limits = [string.split('-')]
    return limits

def ranger(string):
    results = []
    ranges = separator(string)
    for element in ranges:
        start = int(element[0])
        stop = int(element[1]) + 1
        results += [range(start,stop)]
    return results

print ranger(raw_input("Enter a range: "))
```

## Output

*(if the input is `1-100,110-120,140-15`)*:

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100],
[110, 111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119, 120], 
[140, 141, 142, 143, 144, 145, 146, 147, 148, 149, 150]]
```

Comment: This code is working, but one problem, in a text field 1-100,110-120,140-150 how to do that.

Comment: @ K DawG it is working fine, Thank you, my reputation is low so i can't put vote, for this great answer.

Comment: @user3736293 you can then accept it as the correct answer. see the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: @ K DawG i want these on single list is it possible? [1,2,3,...100,110,111,112...140,141,142...] how to do this format.

Comment: @user3736293 Flatten the output list

Comment: Googling "Python flatten list" would be a good starting point.

Answer (score 3):

Use `range()`:

```
low = int(raw_input('Enter the bottom number: '))
high = int(raw_input('Enter the top number: '))
print range(low, high+1)
```

This runs as:

```
Enter the bottom number: 110
Enter the top number: 120
[110, 111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119, 120]
```

---

```
Enter the bottom number: -50
Enter the top number: -10
[-50, -49, -48, -47, -46, -45, -44, -43, -42, -41, -40, -39, -38, -37, -36, -35, -34, -33, -32, -31, -30, -29, -28, -27, -26, -25, -24, -23, -22, -21, -20, -19, -18, -17, -16, -15, -14, -13, -12, -11, -10]
```

## Edit:

Or, if the user enters a string:

```
low, high = raw_input('Enter the range separated by a hyphen (10-20): ').split('-')
print range(int(low), int(high)+1)
```

This runs as:

```
Enter the range separated by a hyphen (10-20): 10-20
[10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20]
```

---

```
Enter the range separated by a hyphen (10-20): 100-150
[100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110, 111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119, 120, 121, 122, 123, 124, 125, 126, 127, 128, 129, 130, 131, 132, 133, 134, 135, 136, 137, 138, 139, 140, 141, 142, 143, 144, 145, 146, 147, 148, 149, 150]
```

Comment: It looks like OP wants `high + 1`

Comment: Lol, that revision history.

Comment: Thank you but user giving the value 10-20 how to split.